# QGIS - set custom default legend symbol for a layer

Tags: qgis, symbology, print-composer, legend

I am aware that I can [change the symbol representing a layer in the legend manually](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_legend.html#customizing-legend-items).

In order to save time I want to prepare a style which includes the changed legend symbol, while preserving the desired display on the map canvas. More precisely, I want the symbology to be a simple outline, while the legend symbol should be a SVG-marker.

I checked with the symbology and legend-tab in the layer properties, but couldn't fit a place to modify the legend-symbol. Is this possible? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to replace any layer style with any custom symbol in the legend panel (polygons to lines, lines to punctual SVG symbol...), for example, a simple outline, same as the polygons or a marker with colors :

[image]

To get an SVG instead of a simple outline, check custom symbol for each item of your legend you want to change :

[image]

Then, select centroïd fill and set it to a SVG marker (or one of the simple default symbol like here) :

[image]

Comment: If you check the link I posted in my question, you see that I am aware of this possibility. So currently this doesn't answer the question, sorry.

Comment: Sorry I missread the question. Maybe, you can take a look in the .qgs file using notepad++, the <layer-tree-group> part might be interesting to reproduce a specific legend style in multiple layouts.

Answer (score 0):

@Erik this is a really interesting question, which unfortunately is not easy to answer at the moment, as QGIS lacks functionality here.

As I could find out, also with QGIS 3.26 it is not possible to save legend placeholder images in layer styles. Legend placeholder images are only stored in QGIS projects. It would be really nice to have this placeholders exported to .qml as well, so that we can store them in our datasources (i.e. PostGIS, GeoPackage) as default styles. I'm pretty sure it's possible to recreate this feature at the moment with some python expression code, but imho it should be directly integrated in QGIS. And it would be beneficial if legend placeholders could also be displayed with legend text, which doesn't seem to work at the moment either.

If @ndawson or one of the other experts can find time to add this feature, they should also add the possibility to save legend placeholder images as inline symbols via the expression editor.